# Register Assembly programmatically

Tags: c#, com, com-interop, regasm, dllregistration

I am trying to register a dll, that extends my contextmenu, programmatically. If I am using the commandline and call regasm.exe everything works fine - my shell extension is visible in the contextmenu. If I am using the following code, RegistrationServices.RegisterAssembly returns true, but my extension is not visible in the context menu. I tried both ways to receive my assembly shown below. Non of them worked. Any suggestions?

```
string path = Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location);
RegistrationServices reg = new RegistrationServices();
Assembly assembly = typeof(ContextCopyPathExtension.ContextCopyPathExtension).Assembly;
//Assembly assembly = Assembly.LoadFrom(path  + "\\ContextCopyPathExtension.dll");
bool done = reg.RegisterAssembly(assembly, AssemblyRegistrationFlags.SetCodeBase);
```

Comment: are you sure you're executing regasm and your code in the same security context (admin vs non admin, same user, etc.)? in the same bitness (32bit vs 64bit) context?

Comment: oh wow, thank you so much - stupid me...i just compiled it using the any cpu configuration. after switching to x64 everything worked fine. Thanks man!